# What's the difference between analog and digital sound ouput when connected by USB?

Tags: fedora, audio

I have Kanto TUK powered speakers on Fedora 30 machine. They have USB input which I use. On Fedora's side the connection can be changed either to analog or digital outputs. I'm wondering what is the difference there and should I try get them working on digital. Right now I have them connected as analog, because when switching to digital it does not always start playing, and when it does it takes one volume up/down button press on a remote and it bugs out. Basically I'm wondering whether I would get any difference in sound quality?

Answer (score 0):

Usually in ALSA and Pulseaudio, "digital" means a soundcard with IEC 958 or SPDIF via coax or optical connection to an amplifier, while "analog" means a soundcard with a D/A converter, with an analog connection to speakers etc. This is selected on the sound card.

I have no idea how this applies to your "Kanto TUK speakers with USB input". Assuming "USB input" means "the speakers present themselves as a soundcard" (which would be easy to check with `lsusb`), then it entirely depends on what the "speakers" (or rather the USB soundcard integrated into the speakers) do with that setting.