# What is the difference between 'digital' and 'analog' audio outputs?

Tags: gnome, audio, alsa

Gnome allows selecting between these two options when a USB audio device (such as a DAC or an amp) is connected. How they differ exactly?

Assuming a modern Linux distribution using [ALSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture), playing digital audio. [The proprietary MQA format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Quality_Authenticated) and some DRM support may fall outside the scope of this question.

[image: Gnome sound settings]

Comment: [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585874/whats-the-difference-between-analog-and-digital-sound-ouput-when-connected-by-u) asks about directly connected speakers and [the one on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57319/analog-and-digital-audio-output-at-the-same-time) is, of course, about Ubuntu.

Comment: For clarity, 'system sounds' refers to the OS audio.

Answer (score 3):

First, we should establish that sounds live on computers in a purely digital format. 1s and 0s recorded onto the storage system (unless your storage is tape... but we won't go in to that). When I instruct my system to play 'Music.mp3', it can't just spit out the 1s and 0s straight to the speaker and have it be intelligible music. It must first pass it through a DAC (Digital to Analog Converter) in order for it to become the analog signal that speakers can use to make sounds our ears understand.

So what does it mean when the system says that an output device is digital or analog? It is informing you where the digital-to-analog conversion is happening, either using the DAC built into your system and sending the resulting analog signal to, say, the 3.5mm jack, which would be an analog output. Or it will stream the digital file to an external DAC over USB, S/PDIF, HDMI, etc, and letting the remote side's DAC handle turning it into audible sounds, which would be a digital output.

Comment: re: "audible sounds" the analog is analog electronics, it does not refer to sound, speaker physically moving makes the sound. What comes out of your sound card is binary data or an analog electronic signal that something else will turn into actual sound.